# how to exclude typescript compiled files from git

Tags: git, typescript, gitignore

I have a visual studio solution with a few asp.net 5 project. Inside every project I have a **wwwroot** directory and inside this an **app** directory that contains the html views, .js and .map files that are typescript files compiled in this position.
  With the standard configuration these files are included in the checkin. How can configure the .gitignore file so all the **.js and .map** files, inside every subdir of the **wwwroot\app** directory of every project in the solution are ignored?

Comment: If you have multiple projects and all projects need same set of git ignore rules, then you can use **Global Git ignore rules** concept to mention single gitignore file and use across all of your projects rather than creating individual gitgnore files. But this global git ignore file won't be a shared copy and your other teammates will not get benefited. Please refer [Atlassian Git](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/gitignore) to check the steps.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
wwwroot/app/**/*.js
wwwroot/app/**/*.map
```

The `**` will match everything inside `app`, also multiple levels of subdirectories.

Comment: what happend if you have a js that is not a compiled file, for example a library?

Comment: @DiegoGonzález libs should go in a separate folder, not in `/app` (eg `/lib`, `/node_modules` etc)

Comment: @Jay One problem with putting output into a separate folder is your code isn't running in the exact same context as the src so, for example, if you `fs.readFile('./foo.md')` then it'll fail -- unless you have a separate copy task to move all non js files into the /dist directory. IMO tsc should allow you to output with a custom file extention, e.g. `.compiled.js` which can then be explicitly ignored

Comment: *.js coverss *.js.map also

Comment: @Technotronic Wouldn't that be `*.js.*`?

Answer (score 22):

Add the following lines to your .gitignore:

```
# Ignores compiled TypeScript files
**/wwwroot/app/**/*.map
**/wwwroot/app/**/*.js
```

You can read more about gitignore and supported patterns [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

`**` matches subdirectories recursively. The first one is there for the projects, the second one is there because you mentioned

> inside every subdir of the wwwroot\app directory